# Concatenate Date and Time into the same column

Tags: r, date, time

I´ve already searched for answers for this here, but nothing seems to work with me.
I am trying to combine date and time into the same column. I have:

```
Data_Extincao    HoraExtincao
2014-03-16       16:15:00
```

But I wanna have: *DataHoraExtincao = 2014-03-16       16:15:00*

I´ve already tried this:

```
dataHoraExtincao <- as.POSIXct(as.character(paste(incendios2014$data_extincao, incendios2014$hora_extincao)), format="%Y/%m/%d %H.%M.%S")

dataHoraExtincao <- as.POSIXct(as.character(paste(incendios2014$data_extincao, incendios2014$hora_extincao)), format="%Y/%m/%d %H%M:%S")

dataHoraExtincao <- as.POSIXct(paste(incendios2014$data_extincao, incendios2014$hora_extincao), format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But every single time I´m getting NAs.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `paste` and apply the `as.POSIXct`.  The `format` here is the default format i.e. `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.  It is not necessary to specify the format when it is the default format

```
with(incendios2014, as.POSIXct(paste(Data_Extincao, HoraExtincao)))
#[1] "2014-03-16 16:15:00 EDT"
```

---

In the OP's code, the `format` code is not the same as the one showed in the example.  Similarly, the column names specified were lower case (`R` is case-sensitive)

#### data

```
incendios2014 <- structure(list(Data_Extincao = "2014-03-16", HoraExtincao = "16:15:00"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```